# Apple developer account teams not showing up on VS Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac, apple-id, apple-developer

When I log in my apple id account on Visual Studio Mac Community 2017, teams doesn't show up.
Do I have to have a paid apple developer account to use this?

There are no team displayed, and the button "View Details..." doesn't do anything.
Also, the icon on the left side of the account is a smiley face icon and it should be a user icon in the [official tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/apple-account-management/).

Screenshot:
[image: Account menu in VS Mac preferences]

While it works perfectly on Xcode:
[image: Works perfectly on Xcode]

Environments:
    - Xcode commandline installed.
    - Fastlane installed.

What troubleshooting I have already done:
- Reinstall Fastlane.
- Use other accounts (none of them worked).
- Use Xcode to log in (screenshot above).
- Try to find anyone had the same problem online and didn't find any.

Comment: Yes, If we use an unpaid Apple ID, teams will not show this account on VS for Mac. But you can add your account in XCode like your screenshot. Then check the automatically manage signing. After running the project on XCode with a real device, the keychain has already added your certification. At last you can deploy your project on real device with VS too.

Comment: I am having the same issue. This seems to be designed by the enemy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case of a personal free account, teams won't appear in VS but will appear in XCode. Every time you need to generate new provision you have to:

1. open XCode with some kind of test project
2. set the targeted bundle id in plist (this step is important as long as provision is tightly coupled with the bundle id)
3. deploy to a device from XCode, it will generate all the required cert/profiles and saves on the Mac
4. go to VS, make you your bundle id in the real app is the same you
   just generated provision for
5. hit run on a device - it
   should work just fine

Comment: This was the only way I could test with Xamarin on a free developer account. I just have to keep a blank single page app open in Xcode on the properties page and change the bundle ID, debug deploy to the device, then go back to Xamarin and re-deploy and it changes the app and app icon. I wonder if there is a way to automate this process into a first time build script?

Comment: What do you mean by "set the targeted bundle id in plist"?

Comment: type in the bundle id there, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you. Deploying the app using Xcode, then do the same using Visual Studio (with the same bundle id `com.xxx.<app_name>`) did the trick. After creating another account and making sure it isn't linked to an Apple Developer Account. Seriously, the whole thing seems to be designed by the enemy.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying with the free account, teams won't appear in VS but you can see in Xcode. Follow the below step to test the application in the device.

1. Open Xcode with some kind of test project.
2. Set the targeted bundle id in plist.
3. Select the respected team and choose automatic provisioning profile. It will generate all the required cert/profiles and saves on the Mac
4. Deploy the app in device from Xcode.
5. Go to VS, use the same Bundle ID which we used in Xcode to run the app.
6. Hit run on a device - it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this for me, In Visual Studio for Mac, I:

1. Opened info.plist
2. Set option to manually provision
3. Click on bundle signing options button
4. Go to the IOS Bundle Signing category
5. Clear out the file listed in the “Custom Entitlement” field.

**Note:** This does not answer the question as to why the original poster’s personal team (used with unpaid developer account) does not show up in Visual Studio for Mac BUT it does solve the problem for why you want you unpaid developer team account to show up (for delvelopment!). Which is inherently why original poster asked the question.