# Could not find any available provisioning profiles for iOS

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios

We are developing a iOS shopping cart application in c# and visual studio 2017 for xamarin. I have an iPad Air iOS 10.3, when I try to publish to real device, I am getting the following error message: "Could not find any available provisioning profiles for iOS", I have tried to restart my Mac - without result. Give me any suggestion to resolve this issue?

Comment: You have an Apple Developer account and created the Provisioning profiles for your app? Also, did you downloaded the provisioning profile you created to the Mac you're working on?

Answer (score 53):

In Visual Studio for OSX, go to *Visual Studio Community > Preferences > Publishing > Apple Developer Account* and click to *+* button to sign in and add your developer account. In theory after that automatic provisioning should work.

In Visual Studio for Windows, go to *Tools > Options > Xamarin > Apple Accounts*, you will get a prompt to install FastLane before your Apple ID will show up under Automatic Provisioning.

Comment: dont see any of these in VS for Mac nor in XCode

Comment: Correct resolution!!!
works for me

Answer (score 34):

You must create a provisioning profile. Search on Google, how to do it.

But, the secret is: when you create a provisioning profile, you must associate an **App ID** to this profile, like: **"com.companyname.*"**.

When you create your app in visual studio, you must set in the **INFO.PLIST** file on IOS PROJECT, the **Bundle Identifier** to **"com.companyname.myapp1"** or anything else.
If your Bundle Identifier has a name like "com.myapp.app1", you will get this error: **Could not find any available provisioning profiles for iOS**, because your profile accept only apps with the names started with **com.companyname** and you are using a appname different.

Comment: I dont know why your suggestion got down-voted but it is correct.  I did same and it works for me.

Comment: Also the solution for me in my MAUI app

Answer (score 20):

For those who just want to deploy/test their app on a real device with "Free provisionning" follow this [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos).

To sum it up :

- Create an apple id
- Add the previously created apple id to XCode in order to add a provisioning profile.
- Create a new empty iOS app with the bundle identifier equals to the one of your Xamarin app (you can find it in Info.plist of your Xamarin.iOS project).
- Ensure that your empty iOS app could be deployed, by running it from XCode on your device with your free provisioning profile.
- In Visual Studio open `Info.plist` and click on `Bundle Signing Options...`, in `Signing identity` chose `Developper automatic` and  `Automatic` in `Provisioning profile`.
- Run your Xamarin.iOS app on your device.

Answer (score 11):

You can see what was wrong with your provisioning profile in xCode. Also this procedure will update Provisioning profiles, Certificates, App Ids:

1. Go to xCode, create blank iOS application, type the same Bundle Identifier, that you had in Visual Studio.
2. On the same page uncheck "Automatically manage signing". 
   [image: Provisioning Profiles in xCode]
3. In Signing (Debug) click on Provisioning profile. You will see Eligible and Ineligible provisioning profiles. You can select each of them and if one is Ineligible, then errors will be shown below. After that you can fix them.
4. After that you can go to Visual Studio for Mac and create the same project with the same bundle id and check you profile in Project -> Options -> iOS Bundle Signing -> Provisioning profile
   [image: Provisioning profiles in Visual Studio for Mac]
5. After that you will find your Provisioning profile in Visual Studio on Windows

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you read [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/?tabs=vsmac) to learn more about iOS provisioning.

What you want is called **[automatic provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning)** though. It takes care of all the complex things about provisioning for you and just deploys the app.

Visual Studio on Windows has the automatic provisioning feature in preview (called 15.7) right now (preview 3): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-preview-relnotes#xamarin-provisioning.
I recommend you try that, it should help you automatically add your iPad to the relevant provisioning profile.

Visual Studio for Mac has had automatic provisioning for a couple releases now.

*Note: you do need an Apple Developer account to deploy on device (it can be a free developer account).*

Comment: As of July 2018 Visual Studio for Windows doesn't do automatic provisioning for iOS devices

Comment: The 15.7 release notes link is dead, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.7#xamarin-provisioning if you still want to view it

Answer (score 8):

Unbelievable but true...

To enable the interface, I first had to login with my Apple account under:
https://itunesconnect.apple.com
and
https://appleid.apple.com
and agree the new privacy agreement from Apple. There isn't any error message that points you in this direction ("you first have to agree...").

After doing that, I was able to use the automatic provisioning in VS2017 and connect to the Mac.

Comment: No help to me, I followed same you stated but in VS for Mac IOS Bundle Signing, I see Provisioning Profile dropdown being disabled

Answer (score 3):

All of these answers are right.

There are many reasons the creation of the provisioning profile certs bundle can fail. The one I dont see listed here is referenced in ([Apple developer account teams not showing up on VS Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593068/apple-developer-account-teams-not-showing-up-on-vs-mac))

Only XCode can set up the provisioning for you using the free apple dev Id. You need to create a dummy project with the same Bundle Name and Bundle Identifier. Build it in XCode and have XCode create the certs for you.

Only once i did that (on the paired Mac) did it start actually building my iOS target in Windows VS 2017

Answer (score 1):

How did I have to solve this?

**First background**

I have already provisioning profile for app we are building but every once in a while I have to create a small POC app to prove something.  And often I have to use that small app on real provisioned device.

But I was not even able to see my device for that small POC app in the dropdown showing available devices.  Only the app I am building with my team will show.

**Solution**

To resolve this, I had to do

1. In my POC app > Info.plist, make sure your Bundle Identifier is same as for the app that you can deploy to your device
2. At the same location, under Signing, select "Automatic Provisioning" and you should see your Apple ID show.  In Team dropdown, select your team

After this, my device showed, I was able to build and deploy to it and the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all the above-mentioned approaches but didn't work. I was using Manual provisioning.

**To identify why it's not showing in VS, I have:**

1. Opened the Xamarin.ios project in Xcode.
2. Under Settings > Manual provisioning profile,> Selected the appropriate certificate (Note: It should be installed before it appears in the list).
3. It showed me an error, which said "Selected provisioning doesn't match with the distribution certificate in the keychain"
4. When I logged into developer.apple.com - I have found a new distribution certificate.
5. I had to regenerate the provisioning profile with the new distribution certificate (selected) and installed it.
6. After installing the error went away.
7. Also, In the Visual Studio's drop-down list the provisioning profile started to appear.

I agree with `Meekohi & Vincent Dondain` who have recommended choosing Automatic Provisioning, as it's a better option if one is not facing any issues with certifications or profiles as it takes care of everything. However, using the latest Visual Studio for Mac is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

just hit the same problem. didn't find solution in this thread that i came to.
Xamarin app, visual studio for mac . manual signing

didn't use it for few months. 
works good on emulator but can't deploy to device for debugging

after reading this thread went to developer.apple.com and found, that my developer profile expired a month ago.

1. create new provisioning profile
2. visual studio for mac-preferences-apple developers account-details-download manual profiles
3. info.plist-bundle signing options-choose correct identity and profile

Answer (score 0):

Answer ( I have had this issue 2 times by switching MACS & adding new applciations )

Issue: Profile not showing up in dropdown below ( Automatic Distribution or Distribution )

As long as you are sure your info.plist is ok and have matching ( com.companyname.something ) & your CERTS are in Keychain then this is what is what cleared it up for me 2 TIMES !

** This seems to be some sort of refresh issue ( where a old profile is cached OR newer profile/bundle not loading in MAC )

[ I use VS on Windows and connect to MAC ]

1. Open Visual Studio for MAC ( not windows )
2. Create a new ( blank form ) iOS project
3. Click Visual Studio in Menu and Click Preferences
4. Click Apple Developer Accounts ( ADD YOUR APPLE ACCOUNT )
5. CLICK VIEW DETAILS & DOWNLOAD ALL PROFILES & Close
6. Open info.plist in your Folder View in VS
7. Check Manual Provisioning & Type in bundle Identifier com.companyname.whatever & App name
8. SAVE
9. RUN BLANK APP & CLOSE IT
   10 ********* Go back to Windows right click on iOS Project Select Distribution AND YOUR BUNDLE IS IN THE DROP DOWN !!

[ If bundle not there re-connect to MAC right click and see if its there in your dropdown - remember the bundle must be in your iOS project ( root ) ]

( Automatic distribution will work as your bundle will be in the dropdown below in Windows Visual Studio & RELEASE TO APP STORE ).

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason could be that there is no Provision profile file

For MAC the path is `/Users/apple/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`

You need to download the corresponding provision file from apple developer account and then paste it here in the above directory

Then, it will start reflecting in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a valid [development certificate](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list), it is added to your Keychain, and that you are signed into Xcode (Settings > Accounts).