# Cannot deploy iOS app to app store or actual device despite working provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I previously released my app to the iOS store but my certificates expired and so I created new certificates and profiles. I am using Xamarin Forms on Windows with a paired Mac. Everything is up to date.

I followed all of the steps in this answer already: [Could not find any available provisioning profiles for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758320/could-not-find-any-available-provisioning-profiles-for-ios)

I am able to see my provisioning profile in Xcode and release the project there with the same bundle identifier as my Xamarin project. It even works when I use Automatic Provisioning and a device simulator. But, when I run either Automatic or Manual Provisioning and try to deploy to an actual device I get the same error "Could not find any available provisioning profiles on iOS".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please check in your iOS .csproject file, search for Debug and Release configuration and check if proper profile is applied or not, otherwise it will give you this same error.

Comment: @MShah Thank you for the reply. The profiles are the same in the .csproj file and the bundle signing tab.

Comment: Please check that profiles applied to both, Debug-iPhoneSimulator and Debug-iPhone.

Comment: @MShah I have the development profile setup for both iPhoneSimulator and iPhone. In fact, I can run manual provisioning just fine when I use the simulator, but when I switch to an actual device I am told "The specified iOS provisioning profile '...' could not be found."

Comment: You can try  on visual studio for Mac. It works on my visual studio  for mac.