# Automatic Provisioning in Xamarin iOS Project

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I cannot get a brand new (i.e., I haven't added anything yet) iPhone project in Visual Studio 2017 to deploy the app to an iPhone attached to my Mac build server (a Mac Mini). It runs fine in the VS simulator.

The problem appears to be related to VS not being able to set up provisioning correctly. I've defined my Apple Developer ID in VS, and can successfully connect to the Mac build server (so I presume all the necessary software is in place on the Mac). But VS can't find the list of Apple "teams", complaining about not being able to communicate with the build server (even though the Pair to Mac dialog claims the connection is up and valid).

The online documentation I'm following at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=vsmac states that there is an entry on the Project menu for Automatic Provisioning... However, it does not appear in VS (I'm running 15.7.4, or whatever the latest available was on 7/8/2018; I may have the .4 wrong).

**Additional Info**

I found this stackoverflow article: [Apple developer account teams not showing up on VS Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593068/apple-developer-account-teams-not-showing-up-on-vs-mac), which states that the Xamarin automatic provisioning doesn't support, at least currently, the free Apple developer account. Which is what I had.

Unfortunately, even after I upgraded to a paid Apple developer account, and re-entered my developer ID in XCode, the Xamarin auto provisioning still doesn't work. I'm not sure if that's because the earlier credentials were cached somehow or what; all I know is that Xamarin is not doing what it claims it can do.

How do I properly configure VS so that Xamarin will be able to work?

Answer (score 0):

I got the build/deploy process to work, finally. I'm not sure how. I think it involved deleting and re-adding my Apple Developer account to Visual Studio 2017 on Windows.

It may also have involved creating a new project within XCode on my Mac (I did both these things on the theory that upgrading my Apple Developer account from Free to Paid was causing a problem).

You can read more about my experience at https://jumpforjoysoftware.com/2018/07/trying-to-write-my-first-xamarin-ios-app/.